# Any way to sleep on a breakpoint in C# / Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

Is there any way to delay execution of the current thread for a specified period of time when hitting a breakpoint in C# / Visual Studio? 
After sleep, execution should continue.

I know there is a "When hit" feature in VS that allows to execute arbitrary code when hitting a breakpoint (primarily to print information to console) but it's much limited; it doesn't allow to put `Thread.Sleep` or any time-consuming operations (like `for` cycles) there. Delegates / lambda functions are not allowed as well.

I'm working with Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: I doubt you can do this... Why don't you put the sleep in your code directly ?

Comment: Adding to @Thomas - maybe with a construct like: `if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached && maybeSomeOtherCondition) { // Sleep }`.

Comment: I think the breakpoint expression evaluator uses the context at the breakpoint.  If your program had a function that did a sleep that was accessible from the function with your breakpoint you could call that (perhaps if it returned a dummy int value?) But since that may require you to change your code, it may not be what you're after.

Comment: Thomas, because it requires rebuild of the whole project and it's very time-consuming in my particular case. By the way, I'm currently doing it but it's annoying.

Comment: @Corak, it requres rebuilding but basically the question was if it's possible to do that **without** rebuilding.

Comment: @MarkWalker, you are right that it allows to execute accessible code.
But looks like it prevents time-consuming code to be evaluated. From my testing, time threshold is 100 ms.

Compare:  
`{System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(99)}`  
`{System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)}`  

I've put both expressions to "When Hit", results are:  
`Expression has been evaluated and has no value`  
`Function evaluation timed out.`  

Looks like it waits 100 ms for the expression to be evaluated, and if it's still running the debugger it and goes further.

Now the question is: is the 100 ms threshold configurable...

Comment: @dimnnv - couldn't you chain multiple 100ms delays? For how long do you want to Sleep()?

Comment: @VladFeinstein, for several seconds. Theoretically that's an option but it yields in tens of breakpoints.

Actually I found out that many timeouts are set in the registry key like `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Debugger` but unfortunately there is no 100 ms timeout there.

Answer (score 0):

I have a native solution that requires a one-time recompile. I'm sure it can be translated into C# if needed.

Define this structure:

```
struct THREAD_DATA
{
    int ms;
    DWORD id;
    THREAD_DATA(DWORD _id, int _ms) : id(_id), ms(_ms) {};
};
```

and this two functions:

```
DWORD WINAPI PauseThread(LPVOID p)
{
    THREAD_DATA* ptd = (THREAD_DATA*)p;
    HANDLE target = OpenThread(THREAD_SUSPEND_RESUME, FALSE, ptd->id);
    SuspendThread(target);
    Sleep(ptd->ms);
    ResumeThread(target);
    delete p;
    return 0;
}
void PauseCurrentThread(int ms)
{
    THREAD_DATA* ptd = new THREAD_DATA(GetCurrentThreadId(), ms);
    HANDLE h = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &PauseThread, (LPVOID)ptd, 0, 0);
}
```

When you are on the breakpoint, use the Immediate Window to run:
`PauseCurrentThread(5000)` or whatever your delay in milliseconds should be.

If you want to do it in multiple project without instrumentation - I could probably develop a Visual Studio extension to do it automagically.